# Is it possible to add Yakkety or Zesty repositories to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, apt, 16.10, software-sources

So, is it possible to add Yakkety or Zesty repositories to Ubuntu 16.04?
I mean I would like to add something like this `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty main universe` to `sources.list` file. Will I get errors or another problems with packages? My current system is `Ubuntu 16.04`.

Comment: Don't do it - down that path lies great frustration and a full reinstall. You are likely to get MANY errors and problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst is possible to do such thing, most people wouldn't recommended it. It will most likely cause a mess, when you do `sudo apt-get upgrade` you'll ended up upgrading several package from different release which is annoying.

If you want install specific package from later release, your best bet would be Apt Pinning. With the help of Pinning, you can install desirable package plus their dependencies safely.

For more information, consider read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto for details.